# White-space: pre-wrap messes up flexbox layout in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout, flexbox

I'm using nested flexboxes to create a layout where

1. No fixed `width` or `height` for inner containers
2. Bottom `div` grows vertically to hold contents
3. Top `div` takes over all extra vertical space
4. Bottom `div` has 2 `span`s, left bottom and right bottom
5. Left bottom `span` grows horizontally to hold contents
6. Right bottom `span` takes over all extra horizontal space
7. Words wrap in middle and white space is not collapsed

It was easy to enough to get 1-6 working, but for some reason setting `white-space: pre-wrap` completely messes up the layout with IE 11, when it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox. If I leave the `white-space` property out, flexbox layout looks nice in IE as well, but white-space gets collapsed and e.g. indentation is lost.

**Any suggestions how to work around this to get it working in IE as well?**

Here's a Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emMeqg

and here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="top"><div>TEXT</div><div>MORE TEXT</div><div>   INDENTED TEXT</div></div>
    <div class="bottom"><span class="bottom-left">BOTTOM LEFT</span><span class="bottom-right">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam imperdiet porttitor pharetra. Vivamus venenatis venenatis blandit. Donec id hendrerit magna, quis bibendum sem. Mauris quis eros ac urna mattis porttitor. In orci metus, porta at consectetur at, fermentum non lectus. Praesent commodo pulvinar iaculis. Fusce vestibulum tincidunt nisi, in venenatis lacus ornare ac. Etiam sit amet blandit orci. Vestibulum lorem orci, porttitor id eros quis, blandit pellentesque turpis. Etiam dignissim, ante sed mollis mattis, ligula risus lacinia leo, vitae tincidunt nisl libero a turpis.</span></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border: green solid;
    line-height: 1;
    word-break: break-all;
}
.top {
    flex: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    background-color: blue;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.bottom {
    flex: none;
    background-color: red;
    display: flex
}
.bottom-left {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    background-color: yellow;
    flex: none;
}
.bottom-right {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    background-color: cyan;
    flex: auto;
}
```

**EDIT**

Code updated to match answer...was enough to move `white-space: pre-wrap` to inner elements. I'll keep the question in case someone faces similar issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, of course I figured it out just after asking...

It looks like it was as simple as moving the `white-space` property from outer `div` to the inner elements, as the extra spacing was caused by line breaks in code between different `div` elements. For some reason IE factors these line breaks in whereas other browsers don't.

I'll update the Pen and code accordingly, maybe this is helpful for someone else..